# Add a colon after two characters without using PHP preg_match

Tags: php

I am currently using `preg_match` to insert a colon after the **second character** of a **four-character** string (1000). I think it is an elegant solution. But I wonder if there are any other elegant solutions for this? Thanks for your ideas!

**Working code**

```
$string = '1000';
$r = preg_replace('/^.*(\d{2})(\d{2})$/', '$1:$2', $string);
print_r($r);

// output "10:00"
```

Comment: @DengSihan Thank you! These are two elegant possibilities. I think that is too more a answear as a comment! it's too good to be just a comment.

Comment: @CedricIpkiss Merci for link but i would say more no than yes! For example, the implode method, which is very good, has not yet been listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the position, then it's faster to use `substr`:

```
$n   = 2;
$str = substr($str, 0, $n) . ':' . substr($str, $n);
```

Or you can use [`substr_replace`](https://www.php.net/substr_replace) to the same effect.

```
$str = substr_replace($str, ':', $n, 0);
```

If this is a *time* (i.e. hours and minutes), you can extract the components in case you need them (in some cases, it's clearer, even if less efficient).

```
$mm  = $str % 100; // Note that this is a number: 8, not 08.
$hh  = ($str - $mm) / 100;

$str2 = sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hh, $mm);
```

Comment: ! String Funtion is a good idea! Merci